# Find a basis of the eigenspace associated with the eigenvalue 4 of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[I've been trying to solve this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7uw1.png)

I did A-4I then tried to find the values of x,y,z and t. However I can't seem to find a basis.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You indeed have to solve the following system of equations:
$$ A-4I =   \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0& 0 \\ -4 & 0 &0 &12 \\ 2& 0 &0 &-8 \\0 &0 &0& -4\end{pmatrix} = 0\,. $$
This gives the following:
$$\begin{cases} -4x +12t &=0\,, \\ 2x-8t &=0\,, \\ -4t&=0\,. \end{cases}$$
From the last equation, you can easily read off a solution: $$\begin{cases} x = 0 \,, \\ t =0 \, .\end{cases} $$
This means that the kernel of $A-4I$ is given by
$$\Bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix}0\\\mu \\\nu\\0\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^4 \, | \, \mu,\nu \in \mathbb{R}\Bigg\}\,.$$
Therefore, you can take as basis $$ \Bigg\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1 \\0 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\0 \\1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}\Bigg\} \, .  $$